# How do I remove the bootstrap input box border using scss?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I am trying to remove the border of the input box. My current code is:

```css
input{
  background-color: #31363A; 
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  border:none;

}
```

How do I remove the annoying white border? 
Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using scss `border: 1px solid [color of the background]`